# Why is AlarmManager.RTC waking my device?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, sleep

I have a very simple alarm manager to do things while the device is awake. So I figured `AlarmManager.RTC` was my best approach. As according to [AlarmManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#RTC) the device is supposed to ignore the next occurring alarm until the device wakes up, then will it send its pending intent instructions.

Here is the code that I have scheduling the Alarm:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WorkerService.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pIntent);
```

And here is the code inside the "WorkerService.class"

```
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    stopSelf();

}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("Service Status", "Service exited");
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Now I know I can write a screen receiver, but then I would have to have another service open to hold that receiver (kinda annoying) when alarm manager is supposed to be ignoring my alarm when the screen is off.

I used `Log.i` to inform me if the service ran. I was able to tell in eclipse's logcat what the output was by using ADB Over WiFi this way the device was allowed to sleep.

Thanks guys, im truly stumped.

Comment: What evidence do you have that your alarm is waking up the device, versus the device being already awake or something else waking up the device? Have you tried a less-insane polling period, like every 15 minutes?

Comment: I have tried 30 seconds with the same result. I will try 15 minutes sir. How did i know you would answer? Im so glad you do because i learn so much from you! You are awesome @CommonsWare !

Comment: CommonsWare is right. You need wait much longer, based on device's configurations and specs. Android does not go sleep right away in order to be ready if user decided to turn it on in a sec later.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirLichonos, i did set to 15 minutes, let the device alone with screen off for a half an hour, it still went off in 15 minute intervals. I might just add a screen off receiver.

Comment: Something else is keeping the device awake, such as ADB over WiFi. You might use **`adb shell dumpsys power`** to see if there are any outstanding wakelocks.

Comment: Hm, its never held a wake lock before, and according to dumpsys there arent any wake locks either... But you are right, there HAS to be something waking it up. Im gonna try again tomorrow with airplane mode on to disable any data communication. My code looks correct though guys? I didn't make a small stupid mistake anywhere?